# Pass Parameter to Generic Method at Runtime

Tags: c#

I'm trying to refactor the following code into a single method

```
if (message.Type == WindowType.DataSourcePickerTest)
{
    var vm = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<DataSourcePickerViewModel>();
    var win = new PickerWindowTest { DataContext = vm };
    var result = win.ShowDialog() ?? false;
    if (result)
        Messenger.Default.Send(vm);
}
else if (message.Type == WindowType.BaselineSave)
{
    var vm = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<BaselineSaveAsViewModel>();
    var win = new BaselineSaveAs { DataContext = vm };
    var result = win.ShowDialog() ?? false;
    if (result)
        Messenger.Default.Send(vm);
}
```

The only difference between the two branches is the type of the ViewModel and Window (vm and win). So far I have

```
private void LaunchWindow(Type viewModelType, Type windowType)
{
    var vm = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<viewModelType>();
}
```

but I'm getting a compilation error 'The type or namespace name 'viewModelType' could not be found'. Is there a way to refactor this if statement without resorting to reflection? Thanks in advance

Comment: In your `LaunchWindow`, `<viewModelType>` is not a type but a parameter. This is what the error message is telling you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could factor out the inner part and call it generically, but it requires that the window class inherit from some base type that have a `DataContext` property (you might also need restrictions on `T` depending on the type of the `DataContext` property):

```
if (message.Type == WindowType.DataSourcePickerTest)
{
    SubMethod<DataSourcePickerViewModel, PickerWindowTest>();
}
else if (message.Type == WindowType.BaselineSave)
{
    SubMethod<BaselineSaveAsViewModel, BaselineSaveAs>();
}

public void SubMethod<T, U>() where U : Window, new()
{
    var vm = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<T>();
    var win = new U { DataContext = vm };
    var result = win.ShowDialog() ?? false;
    if (result)
        Messenger.Default.Send(vm);
}
```

Comment: I guess you need `new()` constraint as well

Comment: @SriramSakthivel for `T` or `U`?  If `WindowBase` is a class that should take care of it.

Comment: @reggaeguitar I made up `WindowBase`.  I didn't know if you had some other base class that they inherited from.

Comment: @DStanley For `U`. No it doesn't. What if I create a `MainWindow` without parameterless constructor? How does the compiler create instance of it? so there must be a `new()` constraint.